# upload multi images from different inputs

Tags: image, reactjs, upload

I want user to be able to change his logo image + home profile image each with different input but when ever I change one of them both changed this is my upload function

```
handleFileUpload( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!e.target.files.length > 0)//user canceled selecting a file
      return  
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var file = e.target.files[0];

      reader.onloadend = ( ) => {
      this.setState({
        imgUrl:  reader.result,
        homeImgUrl:  reader.result,
      });
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  }
```

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags

Comment: Looks like you need to setState based on the target. Your current code sets state for imgIRL and homeImgUrl at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting images from different inputs but setting the same file to both your state values. Instead of this set your state dynamically based on your input name. I'm not accustomed to FileReader but setting state would be like this:

```
handeFileChange = ( e ) => {
    ........
    this.setState( { [ e.target.name ]: e.target.files[ 0 ] } );
    .......
}
```

Input names must match with your state names. This handles file change, then you can use a file upload method. If you want to upload files directly with change, you can use one method for that of course.